# where does vscode store file association overrides?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where does VSCODE store the overridden association of a specific file to a file type?

You can press CTRL K + M and associate a specific file in a project with a specific file type. That association does not apply to other files with the same extension. And does not apply to the same named file in another project.

Is this association stored in project folder somewhere?  I do not see anything in the ./.vscode folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCODE store association of specific file to file type in its own extension module. If you want to override then you need to add it in `settings.json` as per the specific file icon theme implementation.

Icon association depends on the file icon theme. I have tried with vscode icon theme.

- Create folder `vsicons-custom-icons` under `./vscode` directory.
- Create svg icon under `vsicons-custom-icons` folder and follow naming convention:

  - For file: `file_type_<value_of_icon_property>.svg`
  - For folder: `folder_type_<value_of_icon_property>.svg`

  e.g. With the property value `"icon": "mai"` in `settings.json` the file name should be `file_type_mai.svg` or `folder_type_mai.svg`
- Then modify `settings.json` file under ./vscode

  ```
  {
      "vsicons.customIconFolderPath": "./.vscode",
      "vsicons.associations.files": [
      { "icon": "mai", "extensions": ["abc.sql"], "filename": true, "format": "svg", "overrides": "abc.sql" }

      ]

  }
  ```

Comment: as an example, I press CTRL K + M. Associate the current package.json file with SQL. The file icon changes to SQL. The file now has intellisense of an SQL file. But no changes to .vscode/settings.json.   I am interested to know where VSCODE stores this file type association override.

Comment: @StephenRichter, please check I have modified the answer.